# How to check if 1st Datagridview also exists in 2nd Datagridview

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to check my first datagridview to see if it exists in the 2nd dgv. If it does I want to give a error message, and if it doesn't than my 2nd form will load so that the user can add a new pet to the 2nd datagrid. When I click the add pet button nothing happens.

```
Private Sub btnNewPet_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnNewPet.Click
    'validates that user has selected an owner 
    If DGV1.CurrentRow.Index = 0 Then
        MessageBox.Show("You must select an owner.")

        ''If the owner already exist in dgv2 than error message
    ElseIf DGV1.SelectedRows.Equals(DGV2.SelectedRows) Then
        MessageBox.Show("Pet has already been assigned to this owner.")
    Else
        Form2.ShowDialog()
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: It is much easier to use one data source and 2 views of the data; one assigned and one not assigned.  Takes no code to "move" them

Comment: Okay so the add pet form was able to open after selecting an owner in the dgv, but it opens even when the owner has been assigned a pet.

Comment: Comparing one collection to another is just testing the reference, not the contents!   Additionally, comparing collections  to see if one thing is different wont work.  If DGV1 is {1, 2, 3} and DGV2 is {2, 4, 5} and item 2 is in both (assigned) but the collections do not have the same items. So it would fail for item 2 even though it is assigned.

Comment: Okay I think I understand. I'm gonna keep working on it. Thanks!